# RecipientListRouter order of execution

Tags: spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl

I have successfully used RecipientListRouter in my program where based on the value I am sending it to multiple channels.

I would like to know -
1. Will this maintain the order of execution, say in the below case we receive an event that will be processed by both channelChkn and channelDeboard. So, first the event will be processed by channelChkn and then channelDeboard

2. Is it executed in different thread or in the same sender's thread

```
        RecipientListRouter router = new RecipientListRouter();
        router.setIgnoreSendFailures(true);
        router.setApplySequence(true);
        router.addRecipient("channelChkn","headers.get('eventSubType').contains('CHKN')");
        router.addRecipient("channelBkd","headers.get('eventSubType').contains('BKD')");
        router.addRecipient("channelBrd","headers.get('eventSubType').contains('BRD')");
        router.addRecipient("channelDeboard","headers.get('isDeBoarded') == true");
        router.setDefaultOutputChannelName(IntegrationContextUtils.NULL_CHANNEL_BEAN_NAME);
        LOGGER.info("********************* RecipientListRouter *********************"+router.getRecipients());
        return router;
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, they will be executed in order, on the calling thread, as long as all of the recipient target channels are synchronous (no queue channels, no executor channels, no publish-subscribe channels configured with an executor).